# SQL Server need to access from different azure service connection in azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, resources

I have 2 resource group

- RG 1: SQL Server
- RG 2: App service

I am creating a SQL Server user (user would be app service, object id) in RG 2 pipeline where SQL Server is in RG 1 only. Azure service connection of both pipeline is different hence other service connection is unable to find SQL Server since SQL Server is available in RG1 where as pipeline is in RG2.

In that case how can we connect? Appreciate your solutions.

Comment: Hi @amit, How are things going? Have you tried the suggestion in my answer? Is it helpful to you? Please try it, and any progress, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a user can be added into multiple resource groups.

If the user is only in one of the two resource groups, in your case, you can try like as this:

1. In your **Project Settings** on Azure DevOps, create 2 service connections.

- Ask the user who is in **`RG1`** to create a service connection for **`RG1`**.
- Ask the user who is in **`RG2`** to create a service connection for **`RG2`**.

2. In your pipeline, set up a step to connect **`RG1`** using the service connection for **`RG1`**.
3. Set up another step in the pipeline to connect **`RG2`** using the service connection for **`RG2`**.

In this way, you can access the two resource groups in the same pipeline.